# Rounding upwards to the nearest month in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to round upwards to the nearest month. So far, I have:

```
SELECT ROUND(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM') FROM DUAL
```

Which rounds to the closest month, which is upwards in this case. At the time of posting, the output is `03/01/2019` in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

But what if it's the first of a month for example?

```
SELECT ROUND(TO_DATE('01-03-19','DD-MM-YY'), 'MM') FROM DUAL
```

This produces the same output as above. But I am expecting `04/01/2019`.

I could do something like:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('30-03-19','DD-MM-YY'),1), 'MM') - 1 FROM DUAL
```

Which produced the output `03/31/2019`, which is as expected.

I take the 30th March, add one month onto it. Truncate that, to get the first day of that month, then just subtract one for the last day of the previous month.

Now this works, but it seems long and tedious. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: are you trying to find end of the current month?

Comment: @Simonare Yes, I want the final date of the current month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to find last day of the current month

```
LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)
```

if you are trying to find first day of the next month

```
LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) + 1
```